# how to implement or utilize a 'save web form data' feature

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile, tablet

I am creating a web form with jquery/html5/css3 for use with my company. These forms will be used by our techs to go on-site and fill them out and submit it. If there is no wi-fi connection readily available, what is the best way to run these, a feature that will also 'save' web form data incase they want to pull the form up again when Wi-Fi is available and send it that way.

The solution to this answer can be an implementation in jquery (if possible) to use a save button to save form data, or it could be a list of apps to utilize to complete this. What is the best way for the techs to pull up my web app, in an off-line mode and potentially save the values?

keys: taking web app off-line, and saving form data

Comment: You will need to use some sort of persistent storage in-case the mobile device is restarted or the app. is completely closed. Take a look at lawnchair: http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/

Comment: So do your techs all have ipad's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [localStorage](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/) and [appCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid/).

The article for appCache that I linked to explains the best way to determine if user is on or offline. You can then either submit form to server or put in localStorage for later. I can work up a jsfiddle if you would like more detail.

Comment: yes, all my techs have ipads... currently going on-site with pens and papers only for it to be entered again through data entry. the idea is to eliminate data entry and go paperless. i like your provided solution, and will begin implementing it right now. heres another [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-offlineweb/) doing the same thing, they were even kind enough to let us download an example.